# rsync "Permission denied" despite ownership

Tags: centos, permissions, rsync, backup

I just rsync'd a bunch of files, from a Windows box running cygwin sshd, to a CentOS 6.4 box.  I ran `rsync -e sshd...` on CentOS to do this.

Then I plugged in a USB drive on the CentOS box, formatted as ext4 using `mkfs.ext4`, and mounted it at /mnt/backup **(with no extra options)**.  Then I did `chown` on /mnt/backup, and ran `rsync -vrlptg` to copy the files from the CentOS box to /mnt/backup.  A handful of random files (a few dozen of a few hundred thousand, mainly from 4 different directories, but not all of the files in those directories) failed with permissions errors.  But when I `ls -l` on the CentOS box, it shows that I own all of them.

If I `sudo rsync` instead, it copies everything without complaining.

Why does it seem that rsync thinks I don't have permission to copy my own files to my own drive?

**Update**: although earlier it said `myuser` owned them, I've since run a `sudo rsync -e sshd` and now most (but not all) files, despite being in a folder in my home drive on the CentOS box (/home/myuser) are now no longer owned by `myuser myuser` but instead are owned by `513` or `dialout`, which I never set up as users.

Comment: There is not enough detail to provide a full answer, but it seems that the problem is when rsync tries to set the permissions to someone other than you. If you could add an ls -l output of the source files, in the CentOS box, it could shed some more light.

Comment: Can you provide the mount command + options you used to mount the USB drive?

Comment: @DavidKohen, I tried to provide a bit more detail, but I'm generally afraid of exposing sensitive information.  Could you tell me what you're looking for specifically?  Also hopefully my update provided a bigger clue anyway than the original `ls -l` I was looking at might have.  For the Windows->CentOS transfer I thought rsync wasn't able to transfer permissions info (coming from NTFS).  Then from CentOS to the backup I don't understand why it would be trying that nor who these two other users are.

Comment: @slm please see question update too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if your issue is related to this excerpt I found on a blog detailing how to use Cygwin, `rsync`, and `ssh`? Th title of the article is: [SSH and Rsync within Cygwin](http://www.gizmoplex.com/wordpress/ssh-and-rsync-within-cygwin/).

> When using an NTFS file system, Cygwin will, by default, apply
>   posix-style file permissions using NTFS file permissions. In some
>   cases this may not be desirable as this can make it difficult to work
>   with the files on the Windows server outside of Cygwin. This behavior
>   can be altered by modifying the /etc/fstab file. Simply add/edit the
>   line in this file to read as follows:
>
> none /cygdrive cygdrive user,noacl,posix=0 0 0

This would explain why the permissions were showing up as UID 513 or user dialout.

Comment: Just to be clear, this is /etc/fstab on the CentOS box, not within the cygwin terminal on the Windows box?

Comment: @Kev - no I believe that's a fstab file on the cygwin install. I don't have cygwin around so I couldn't confirm this though.

Comment: @Kev - the file is definitely on the cygwin side, it's discussed here in the docs: http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#mount-table